# Only Update Start In field when updating the scheduled task via command promt/powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, task, scheduler

Is it possible to only update the **Start In (Optional)** field (in GUI) when updating the task via command prompt.
Is there like a **flag for /tr to specify the executable file and then the location of the executable file**.
In this sample syntax: ***schtasks /change /tn <task_name> /tr  /ru  /rp*** 
Can we do like **/tr -e -l**

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) Don't know of a way to use `schtasks.exe` without `/XML` to get to the arguments and directory properties. It's an old tool that does not validate program path. "**Start In (Optional)** field" is not available and `.bat` file is recommended for anything with parameters or multiple commands.

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) Assuming uniqe task with <task_name>, only one or first action to update.

```
$action = (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName '<task_name>').Actions
$action[0].WorkingDirectory = "<new path>"
$action[0].Arguments = "<new arguments>"
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName '<task_name>' -Action $action
```